# fetching with PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

i have this link

```
view-source:http://abcast.net/embed.php?file=klaci16&width=750&height=450
```

i want to fetch only m3u8 attribute from the page on other php page

for example , i have this from the link :

```
player = videojs("Player", {
                    "sources"   : [ { "type": "application/x-mpegURL", "src": "http://live.abcast.net:8081/edge/verc9f615461d48dd8b44c84e0b87c50894/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS82LzIwMTcgNTo1OToxOCBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVVPTElSQ3V4NENKM0FoQUhRUWJIYUE9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTIw" } ],
                    "techOrder" : [ "html5", "flash" ],
```

i want to get on other php page only this attribute

```
http://live.abcast.net:8081/edge/verc9f615461d48dd8b44c84e0b87c50894/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS82LzIwMTcgNTo1OToxOCBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVVPTElSQ3V4NENKM0FoQUhRUWJIYUE9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTIw
```

any help please ? i tryied this code but won't working

```
<?php
$url="http://abcast.net/embed.php?file=klaci16";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('player');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
      echo $lol=$tag->getAttribute('src');
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself? If not, now would be the time to do so

Comment: Update what you've done in you question not in the comment section, comment is good for question and answer only.

Comment: ok code insered in the question

Comment: Okay, so what debugging have you done? Have you verified that the content of `$html` is what you expect it to be? Have you tried removing the error-suppression (@ sign) on `$doc->loadHtml($html)`? Have you checked the result of that call?

Comment: i tested it but it show white page no result , i think something wrong , i'm not so good in php :/

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents($url); var_dump($html); exit;`  What does that show?

Comment: it show string(6834) and redirect to google page because on the source page there is a redirection

Comment: i want to fetch src of sources but i don't know how

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1. Search the string with strpos to find 'videojs("Player"' - the needle

Step 2. Remove the everything in the string from the position of the needle using substr

**Optional Step** : Find the last closing tag of the videojs - something like ");" and remove the remaining data with substr

Step 3. At this point you could use explode with the delimiter as the " (a bit hackish)

Step 4. This will now give you an array of each parameter that was enclosed in the ""

Step 5. You can now access the array get the required data.

```
<?php
    $url="http://abcast.net/embed.php?file=klaci16";

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $find = 'videojs("Player", ';
    $pos = strpos($html,$find);

    $html = substr($html, $pos+$find,-1); // Position + amount of characters of the needle
    $html = explode('"', $html);
    print_r($html); // What's the key?
    echo $html[11]; // 11 = http://live.abcast.net:8081/edge/verc9f615461d48dd8b44c84e0b87c50894/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS82LzIwMTcgNTo1OToxOCBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVVPTElSQ3V4NENKM0FoQUhRUWJIYUE9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTIw
?>
```

Comment: for this line  $html = 'player = videojs("Player", {
                    "sources"   : [ { "type": "application/x-mpegURL", "src": "http://live.abcast.net:8081/edge/verc9f615461d48dd8b44c84e0b87c50894/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS82LzIwMTcgNTo1OToxOCBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVVPTElSQ3V4NENKM0FoQUhRUWJIYUE9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTIw" } ],
                    "techOrder" : [ "html5", "flash" ],';    on page source it's dynamic not static , every refresh F5 it give new m3u8 LINK

Comment: is there any way to get what you wrote in red with get_file_contents() function ?

Comment: yes i tested your code , it's ok work for static , but i need to get this link " http://live.abcast.net:8081/edge/verc9f615461d48dd8b44c84e0b87c50894/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS82LzIwMTcgNTo1OToxOCBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVVPTElSQ3V4NENKM0FoQUhRUWJIYUE9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTIw " automaticaly , you can do it for me if possible ?

Comment: is there a code to stop fetching the whole page ? only when m3u8 file finish , it stop , i wont show other codes after m3u8

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to buffer the content coming in line by line from a **remote source in php** - you would need to use a different programming language that will allow you to buffer the content.